# Cannot access cookies from frontend React application

Tags: cookies, axios, cors

I'm using the access tokens and refresh tokens for authorization. In the backend Express app, the refresh token is stored in a httpOnly cookie so that an accessToken can be generated from it.

```
res.cookie('jwt', refreshToken, {
  httpOnly: true,
  secure: false,
  maxAge: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
});
```

The refresh endpoint works correctly and logs the cookie **only when tested in Postman**.
I'm using **Axios Interceptors** in the frontend to call the refresh endpoint when the access token expires.

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import { Store } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

let store: Store;

export const injectStore = (_store: Store) => {
  store = _store;
};

const BASE_URL = import.meta.env.VITE_REACT_APP_API_URL;

export const axiosPublic = axios.create({ baseURL: BASE_URL });

export const axiosPrivate = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  withCredentials: true,
});

axiosPrivate.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
    if (!config.headers.authorization) {
      config.headers.authorization = `Bearer ${store.getState().auth.token}`;
      console.log(config.headers);
    }
    return config;
  },
  (error) => Promise.reject(error)
);

axiosPrivate.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => response,
  async (error) => {
    const prevRequest = error?.config;
    if (error?.response?.status === 403 && !prevRequest?.sent) {
      prevRequest.sent = true;
      console.log('Error part');
      const response = await axiosPrivate.get('/api/v1/auth/refresh');
      console.log(response?.data);
      const newAccessToken = response?.data.payload.accessToken;
      prevRequest.headers['authorization'] = `Bearer ${newAccessToken}`;
      return axiosPrivate(prevRequest);
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

Reading about that there can be possible cors error, i have provided the cors file too.

```js
import allowedOrigins from './allowedOrigins';
import { CorsOptions } from 'cors';

const corsOptions: CorsOptions = {
  origin: allowedOrigins,
  credentials: true,
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
};

export default corsOptions;
```

The allowedOrigins contain `const allowedOrigins = ['http://127.0.0.1:5173'];`

Logging the value of cookie in the backend when accessing from frontend, i get **[Object: null prototype] {}**

Comment: Are the [Web origins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin) of your client and server [same-site](https://site-and-origin.securitum.com/)? If not, you'll need to set your cookie with `SameSite=None`, which, in many modern browsers also requires `Secure`. And, because `Secure` requires that the client communicate with the server over HTTPS, you'll need to obtain and install a TLS certificate on your server.